# How do I change SQL connection from one server to another on an an External list

Tags: external-list, database-connection

I have an external list that points to SQL Server A.  Server A is being de-commission and the database is moving to SQL Server B.  I need to change my connection for my lists.
I created a new datastore that points to the new server. I can see my Database in the Data Source Explorer.  I thought all I would need to do would be chagne the External System's Connection Property but when I do that I get an error that states I need to edit the webpart in designer.

How do I change the connection

I am using sharepoint 2010 and designer.  I am looking for an OOB solution.

The error message is
Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer

Comment: Have you tried creating a SQL server client alias (cliconfg.exe) with the name of SQL Server A that points to SQL Server B?

Comment: No, I dont have access to change server names.  But thanks.

Comment: An alias doesn't require a server name change, see http://habaneroconsulting.com/blog/posts/Why_you_should_be_using_a_SQL_Server_Client_Alias.aspx You wouldn't be changing it for the farm, but that article explains the concept and it should work also for any other SQL Server connection